# VBA: Copying next filled row into previous blank rows repeating

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm not very well versed in VBA and can't seem to figure how I would write this.

I have a set of values where I have blank rows that need to be the same as the next row of data.

[image]

So as seen above, I would like rows 1-5 to be the same as row 6.
These gaps do repeat within the set and need those to also be filled similarly.

I've been trying to create something with an if isempty copy the row below but wasn't sure how to go in reverse order for a for loop.

Comment: Reverse order in a loop: `For i = 10 to 1 step -1`

Comment: Use fill up in Power query

Answer (score 1):

### Fill Blank Rows From Below

[image]

```vb
Sub FillBlankRowsFromBelow()
    
    Const FIRST_DATA_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const COPY_VALUES_ONLY As Boolean = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
   
    Dim srg As Range, cCount As Long
    
    With ws.UsedRange ' assuming that 'FirstCell:XFD1048576' is not empty:
        Set srg = ws.Range(FIRST_DATA_CELL, .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
        cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    End With
    
    Dim RowOffset As Long: RowOffset = 1 ' *** all but the first row
    
    Dim srrg As Range, sr As Long, drCount As Long, CopyRows As Boolean
    
    For sr = srg.Rows.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Set srrg = srg.Rows(sr)
        If Application.CountBlank(srrg) = cCount Then ' the row is blank
            drCount = drCount + 1
            If sr = 1 Then RowOffset = 0: CopyRows = True ' *** the first row
        Else ' the row is not blank
            If drCount > 0 Then CopyRows = True
        End If
        If CopyRows Then
            With srrg.Offset(RowOffset)
                If COPY_VALUES_ONLY Then
                    ' Copy only values (faster).
                    .Resize(drCount).Value = .Offset(drCount).Value
                Else
                    ' Copy values, formulas and formats (slow).
                    .Offset(drCount).Copy .Resize(drCount)
                End If
            End With
            drCount = 0
            CopyRows = False
        End If
    Next sr
    
    MsgBox "Blank rows filled from below.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```